# UITableview Moving Cells

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am looking for some advice!

Do you need to (or should you) make tableview cell movements persistent?

I have included the functionality to allow users to move the cells to their own order using the local array which is fine for while the application is in use but I have not written it back to the sqlite database to provide persistence for after the application quits.

At the moment i am thinking of just removing it as im not sure if it really offers anything for our end users but would like to have other opinions (Just in case i need to reprogram it..)

Would an app submitted to the appstore be rejected if it didnt apply persistence for the moving of cells?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had a few apps approved by Apple that do not handle cell row movements, no problem.